# Insert JFrame into a Tab in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

I Have an already given `JFrame frame`, that I want to show it (insert it) into a `tab` of `JTabbedPane`, but that was not possible explicitely like that:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

mainTabs.addTab("Editor", null, frame, null);
```

And the error was:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
```

I tried some solutions like to insert the frame into a `JPanel` but also in vain. I have the idea to convert it into an `InternalJFrame` but I don't have any idea about that.

Is that any solution to insert that `frame`?

**UPDATE**:

I tried that soluion:

```
 mainTabs.addTab("Editor", null, frame.getContentPane(), null);
```

But i lost the `JMenuBar` that I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add `JFrame`(or another top-level component) to another component/container, but you can use `getContentPane()` method of frame, to get main panel of your frame and add that to `JTabbedPane` tab. Like next:

```
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JButton("button"));
tabs.addTab("1", frame.getContentPane());
```

Also you can change `JFrame` to `JPanel` and use that.

Read about [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), [top-level containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

EDIT: `getContentPane()` doesn't return any decorations or `JMenuBar`, this components you need to add manually, like in next example with menu:

```
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
bar.add(new JMenu("menu"));
frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
frame.add(new JButton("button"));

JPanel tab1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
tab1.add(frame.getJMenuBar(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
tab1.add(frame.getContentPane());
tabs.addTab("1", tab1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into `JDesktop` and `JInternalFrame` for that. I think it's the best suited solution for your problem.