# How to insert one Java Application into the tabbed pane of another application

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

My Professor ask me to create one JSwing application which have three tabbed panes each hold a single game.

I have created three different java applications for three different games (Snake, MineSweaper, and Packman) according to [zetcode.com website](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/). Each Application contains a Main Class which hold the JFrame and the main method, and another class (extends JPanel) to create the board of the game and lunch it.

Here is an example:

```
public class Minesweeper_Main extends JFrame {
    JFrame jfrm;
    Container pane;
    JLabel statusbar;

    public Minesweeper_Main () {
        jfrm= new JFrame("Minesweeper");
        jfrm.setSize(500,700);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jfrm.setResizable(false);

        pane=jfrm.getContentPane();

        statusbar = new JLabel("");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new MineSweeper_Board(statusbar));

        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Minesweeper_Main ();
    }
}

public class MineSweeper_Board extends JPanel {
……..
    public MineSweeper_Board(JLabel statusbar) {   
        this.statusbar = statusbar;
        ………
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        addMouseListener(new MinesAdapter());
        newGame();
    }
……..
}
```

Now, I would like to create a new Java Application (Swing Interface), which contains three Tabbed Panes, each hold or call one specific game. Unfortunately, I am either getting error all the times or getting blanks tabs.

The code for the new JSwing application is as following:

```
public class MF_GameHub extends JFrame {
    JFrame jfrm;
    Container pane;
    JTabbedPane jtp;
    public MF_GameHub(){
        jfrm= new JFrame("GameHub");
        jfrm.setSize(500,700);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jfrm.setResizable(false);

        pane=jfrm.getContentPane();

       ………

        jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.addTab("MineSweeper", new MineSweeper());
        jtp.addTab("PacMan", new PacMan());
        jtp.addTab("Snake", new Snake());     

        pane.add(jtp);

        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MF_GameHub();
    }
}
class MineSweeper extends JPanel {
    //I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO CALL THE OTHER JAVA APPLICATION FROM HERE
}

class PacMan extends JPanel {
    //I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO CALL THE OTHER JAVA APPLICATION FROM HERE
}

class Snake extends JPanel {
    //I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO CALL THE OTHER JAVA APPLICATION FROM HERE
}
```

How can I integrate all three games under one application?

Comment: You can't directly add one top level component to another one.This might help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488791/insert-jframe-into-a-tab-in-swing

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I will have split my `JFrame` and the `JFrame`'s `contentPane`.
After that, you just have to use the `contentpane` and import this into your app where you want!

Example with your code:

```
public class Minesweeper_Main extends JFrame {
    Container pane;
    JLabel statusbar;

    public Minesweeper_Main (JPanel contentPane) {
        super("Minesweeper");
        setSize(500,700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        setContentPane(contentPane); // << Add

        setVisible(true);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Minesweeper_Main (new MineSweeper_Pane()); // << Changed
    }
}

public class MF_GameHub extends JFrame {
    Container pane;
    JTabbedPane jtp;

    public MF_GameHub(){
        super("GameHub");
        setSize(500,700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        pane=getContentPane();

       ………

        jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.addTab("MineSweeper", new MineSweeper_Pane());
        jtp.addTab("PacMan", new PacMan_Pane());
        jtp.addTab("Snake", new Snake_Pane());     

        pane.add(jtp);

        setVisible(true);
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MF_GameHub();
    }
}
```

And you add this:

```
public class MineSweeper_Pane extends JPanel {
    public MineSweeper_Pane() {    
        statusbar = new JLabel("");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new MineSweeper_Board(statusbar));
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I'm tired I think; you are using JFrame attribute in a JFrame extended class; Remove the JFrame attribute and use **this** (or nothing) instead of using the attribute jfrm ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I apply your suggestions, I got the following errors in the "Minesweeper_Main" Class. For the "jfrm.setContentPane(contentPane);" I got the error "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable contentPane; location: class Minesweeper". And for the "new Minesweeper_Main (new MineSweeper_Pane());", I got the error "constructor Minesweeper in class Minesweeper cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: MineSweeper_Pane
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 New instance ignored". Any further suggestions ?!! Thanks.

Comment: Hello ! I don't know for your problem, certainly a typo, but I can do one more edition to what I wrote. I edited my last post (the code has changed, and I added 2 lines at the end of the post). Maybe it will correct your problem ;)